# WooCommerce function to display total product sales on site homepage

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to find a function and shortcode to display the total amount of products sold as simply as possible on our website.
Don't want to show product names or any info just a count.
I found this function / shortcode that displays total orders. Just wondering fo anyone can help adapt it to display total products sold?
Thanks so much..

```
function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
    ), $atts );

    $statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;

    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {

        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }

        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }

    ob_start();

    echo number_format( $order_count );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );
```

Comment: where would you want it to display? and what do you mean by total products sold? you mean all the products in the website? count the quantity sold each product? you should be more specific..

Comment: Sorry for not being so specific. I explain. Each order taken contains more than one product normally. Often over 20 products. I want to be able to show the count of all products sold and not all orders. ie Total of products sold.
The shortcode will go on a normal page on the website - outside the WooCommerce loop. By that I mean not connected with the shop.