# Display WooCommerce category total sales count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a membership section on my site and I need to display the number of sales for a single category (including variable products). I'm using the snippet below I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365644/woocommerce-function-to-display-total-product-sales-on-site-homepage), added my category but I'm still getting the count for the whole shop.

```
function memberships_sales_counter( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
        'product_cat' => 'cursos'
    ), $atts );

    $statuses = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;

    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }
        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }

    ob_start();
    echo number_format( $order_count );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'memberships-sales-counter', 'memberships_sales_counter' );
```

To clarify, I don't need the revenue amount, I just need a count for the total number of sales.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831414/10447197). You could use the `counts_total_sales_by_product_category` custom function to get the total sales for a specific product category.

Comment: This requires a custom heavy SQL query… You should better add a custom order meta data 'cursos' to all orders that have items with 'cursos' category when checking out… Then you will be able to make a lighter WP_Query to get all related orders count.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at both suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Vincenzo Di Gaetano, this worked:

```
function memberships_sales_counter( $term_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $total_sales = $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT sum(meta_value)
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id )
        WHERE ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN (2723) )
        AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'total_sales'"
    );
    return $total_sales;
}
add_shortcode( 'memberships-sales-counter', 'memberships_sales_counter' );
```